# PhpMyAdmin "Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!"

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I get this error when I try to access localhost/phpmyadmin:

*Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!*

I have already chmoded every file to 555 from 777. What should I do next? I run Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try this it will work

```sh
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Answer (score 75):

Try

```sh
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

This command fixed the issue having on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I am on Mac OSX with XAMPP and this solution worked with me but with this command: `sudo chmod 755 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Thanks this saved me in 2021!!

Answer (score 46):

This is because of wrong permission of `phpMyAdmin` directory and the file `config.inc.php`

On ***nix** like OS set the permission of the directory and the file as follows

```
chmod -R 755 /path/to/phpMyAdmin
chmod 644 /path/to/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
```

If like me you run a Linux Virtual Machine which mount a Windows folder where `phpMyAdmin` sources are located, edit `config.inc.php` and add this line

```
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
```

Comment: Worked for me. Was running phpmyadmin on vagrant. TY :)

Comment: tried the last option... since I could not change the perms .

Comment: `$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;`
Thanks it work for me

Comment: works form me in ubuntu 20.04.1. But config.inc.php file located at /opt/lampstack-8.0.0-1/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs.

Comment: This worked for me on windows vagrant homestead: config.inc.php was already read-only

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me: `$ pkexec chmod 755 -R /etc/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 14):

For Mac OS users:

Find the file named **config.inc.php**, usually located in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

(this is the filepath on my Mac)

### Then click the right mouse click -> Click on **Get Info**, at the bottom of the box you will find permissions-> click on **the Lock** icon (bottom right corner)

Put your System Admin Password ->
-> where it says **everyone**, modify this permission to **READ ONLY** -> click back on **the Lock** icon and try to open

[http://localhost/phpMyadmin http://localhost/phpmyadmin](http://localhost/phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 11):

You should **not** be making them `777` (which is writeable by everyone). Try `644` instead, which means user has read and write and group and others can only read.

Comment: I have this problem and I changed the permissions but I'm still getting the error. I think there are more steps you can take to troubleshoot...

Answer (score 10):

Just in case, someone out there having same issue but changing file permission doesn't solve the issue, add this line to your `config.inc.php` file

```
<?php
// other config goes here . . . 
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
```

And you're good to go.

---

In my case, I'm using windows 10 WSL with phpmyadmin installed on `D:` drive. There's no way to ([for now](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/81)) change file permission on local disk through WSL unless your installation directory is inside WSL filesystem it-self. There's [updates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/01/12/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/) according to this issue, but still on insider build.

Cheers.

Comment: Great Stuff!  This works since chmod didn't work for me.

Answer (score 9):

I just solved this problem myself, and this question/answer pair was not helpful to me in particular, so I will add what solved it for me in my specific case.

For starters, I have just began to use a repository so I "`chmod 777 -R`"'ed my entire /opt/lampp directory to make sure that permissions were not an issue for the pushing of the repository.  Then I got two errors, but I think I only saw one of them and the next one showed up after fixing the first one it.  I suppose one error was upstaging the other.

The first one was ./lampp/etc/my.cnf  A chmod 700 on that file fixed it in my case although, 755 seems to be the better choice that I found in my research.

One file down, one more to go.  The other file, which is the one causing the specific error message in this question is ./lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php.

Solution: "`$ chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin`"

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem as you. I fixed this problem by following this post :D

But I didn't change the permission from 777 to 755 :O

http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2013/02/19/Solve-Wrong-permissions-on-configuration-file%2C-should-not-be-world-writable!-error-on-phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 4):

all you need is to

1. open terminal type

   opt/lampp/lampp start

to start it and then

2. `sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

then visit in your browser

```
localhost/phpmyadmin
```

it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I run my system on top of a XAMPP instalation on a OS X.

A few days ago I faced the same problem. I was getting a lot of permission problems when installing and managing CMS test platforms, so I decided to set the entire htdocs subtree to a+rwX permissions, and got the same error.

Although my decision to set the entire subtree to those permissions is generally a mistake, that I made knowingly because this system is only accessable by localhost and otherwise unreachable, the only file that needs permission changing to solve this issue is *config.inc.php*, and you can leave the rest with the permissions you think you need.

The problem is fixed with:
**chmod 644 config.inc.php**, or sudo chmod 644 config.inc.php, depending on the system.
(issued inside the phpmyadmin folder)

Comment: Thank you @zejoao2000 It worked for me on Linux mint also. :)

Answer (score 2):

This error occured because phpmyadmin directory has all permissions (777).
you can resolved this problem by executing the following command.

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Answer (score 2):

For Mac
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Do the following in your terminal

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

**After this you have to restart your server**

Answer (score 1):

try if install lampp

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/*
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
```

or if install phpmyadmin

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /etc/phpmyadmin/*
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /etc/phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 1):

What the hell? errors say that the file should not be 755 but everyone says should be `755`.
You should change the permission of the file into 444 to protect it from the edit.

run this command:

```
sudo chmod 444 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mac/ MAMP:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On My Mac using XAMPP i simply did

```
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Answer (score 0):

These problem arises due to permission we can't give the all permission of our database config
If you are using ubuntu and you have the path like this `/opt/lampp` then type the following command in terminal.

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error just appaered this morning, without doing any updates.

If your using the official docker container without Your own config.inc.php, You can find the file located in /etc/phpmyadmin

So the solution would be

```
docker exec nameofyourphpmyadmincontainer chmod 0644 /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

or mount an external config.inc.php into docker container on start.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto lampp folder and change the owner back to root
2. Change permission to 755 -> This will start the phpmyadmin working again
3. Goto htdocs folder and make your user as owner of the folder and give 777 permission so that you can start the localhost project
4. If with step 3 error such as write access denied comes, then for htdocs folder, right click and give permissions to all files/folders recursively

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for macbook users who didn't understand how to navigate to config.inc.php

1. open terminal
2. execute this command `cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin`
3. execute this command `sudo chmod 755 config.inc.php`

Answer (score 0):

For me it wasn't the `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file permissions, but rather `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

After lots of messing around with the /etc/ one, I ran this, which fixed it:

```
sudo chmod 660 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
sudo chgrp www-data /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Answer (score -1):

To restrict access on this file /phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and he will work.

Simple tape this : `sudo chmod 750 /phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` !

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ubutu and you have the path like this /opt/lampp then type the following command in terminal.

```
sudo pkexec chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
```

Hope this will find out your solution.

Answer (score -1):

you should change the owner of the server 
by `chown` command

from home you can run this command

```
sudo chown {userName} -R ../../opt
```

If it does not work yet, run this command

```
sudo chmod 777 -R ../../opt
```

It should work now.