# Linux Mint: Bitnami Xampp access issue

Tags: linux, xampp, bitnami, linux-mint

I have installed Bitnami Xampp on linux mint, it is installed inside /opt/

The application is unable to access(Write/Read) files and hence not able to work on it.

Any Solution Please........

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the previous setting 
--$ sudo chmod -R 777 opt Xampp is not working with following error 
PhpMyAdmin “Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!”

Then I followed [PhpMyAdmin "Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577490/phpmyadmin-wrong-permissions-on-configuration-file-should-not-be-world-writabl) and now working fine...

Thank god it saved me from switching back to Windows. That I hate.....

Answer (score 1):

It is simple access issue. So I need to give read write access to folder and file using chmod command:-

--$ sudo chmod -R 777 opt

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I am don't really know Xampp but with the command you mentioned above you changed the the access rights for the top level directory /opt and thru using 777 you gave basically all rights to everbody using your system. If Xampp now tries to write something, it of course can because you gave it the rights (like to anyone else). 
The -R option you used in the chmod-command above means, that you have changed the access rights for all subdirectories of /opt also (recursively). 
I would recommend that you change this back to the original access rights for /opt and, if you need, just change the access rights for the directory where Xampp is placed. Then Xampp should also work because it can read an write in it's own subdirectory and there won't be any harm for or from other applications from /opt because they can't access /opt/Xampp and Xampp can't access their directories.