# Phpmyadmin not working in ubuntu xampp after changing permission

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using xampp 5.6.20. Unfortunately I have changed permission for `/opt/lampp` to 777 instead of `/opt/lampp/htdocs`. so it was display some warning like `phpmyadmin configuration file is writable.`

Then i have changed permission for /opt/lampp to 755. After that i got this error `Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.` how can i resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Run This command on ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Or if not fixed , try this one:

```
$ pkexec chmod 755 -R /path/phpmyadmin
```

Refer this link[PhpMyAdmin “Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577490/phpmyadmin-wrong-permissions-on-configuration-file-should-not-be-world-writabl)

Hope this helps

Comment: I got this error when i use the second command  `/bin/chmod: cannot access '/etc/phpmyadmin': No such file or directory`

Comment: oh my bad, please adjust the path according to your lampp installtion

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577490/phpmyadmin-wrong-permissions-on-configuration-file-should-not-be-world-writabl

Answer (score 0):

Try to issue this command:

chmod 0755 config.inc.php

PMA doesn't want the config.inc.php to be world writable, in your case, you made it world writable by chmod 777. If it doesn't work, try to issue the command below:

chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin

This will do a recursive chmod on your phpmyadmin folder.

If it still doesn't work, try to remove the phpmyadmin installation and reinstall.

Comment: Then how can I export my database..?